# Bind array of objects of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, model-binding, quasar

```
<q-checkbox 
v-model=“formData.checks.options[].id
/>
Return data:
formData: {
 checks: 
  [{
   options:
     [{
       id: 1
     },
     {
       id: 2
     }]
 },
 {
   options:
     [{
       id: 1
     },
     {
       id: 2
     }]
 }]
}
```

Question -1: In the above scenario, I need to loop through multiple checks with their respective options. Is it a good practice to do two for loops. Say for example, one to loop all checks and second to loop all options with loop 1 index?

Question -2: if I want to check default values for a specific checks list with respective it’s respective option. How can I do it?

Comment: That code isn't valid JavaScript, but perhaps you knew that. I don't understand either of your questions, but it sounds like `Array.prototype.filter()` might be helpful

Comment: 1) formData is a object 2) Checks is an array of objects 3) options are array of objects of checks array respectively. Now how can I bind it to a checkbox with default option as checked in Vue js

Comment: You can use `lodash` functions like [map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#map) to transform the `formData` to something that could be easily consumed by the `q-checkbox`.